# appearance of parts titles

Tags: sectioning, parts

I am writing my thesis which is divided in two parts. 
If I use the following simplified code:

```
\begin{document}

\part{Title of the first part}

...

\part{Title of the second part}

....

\end{document}
```

in the corresponding pdf I visualize "Part I + the title of the first part" (before the contents of the first part) and "Part II + title of the second part" (before the contents of the second part).
Is it possible to visualize in the pdf simply "Title of the first part" (without "Part I") and "Title of the second part" (without "Part II")?
Thanks

Comment: use `part*`? and a manual entry to the toc?

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am using book

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine `\@part` (original in `book.cls`):

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       %\huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       %\par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{A test part title}

\end{document}
```

Using `xpatch` to patch the command makes the code shorter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{A test part title}

\end{document}
```

The result in both cases:

[image]